# How can I force Jedis client to rediscover redis cluster nodes

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis

I have redis cluster running on kubernetes to which I am connecting via Jedis. When connecting to the cluster I use a domain name. This all works fine. Jedis discovers the cluster nodes and everything is good.

The problem occurs when all the nodes in the redis-cluster are restarted. When this happens then Jedis is not able to connect to the cluster anymore because the IP addresses of all the nodes have changed.

In this scenario what can we do on the Jedis side to reconnect to the Redis cluster (other than restarting the client)

I am using jedis 3.6.0